# how to use preg_match_all to remove the <a> tag

Tags: php, regex

```
$content = preg_replace("~(<a href=\"(.*)\">\w+)~iU", '', $content);
$ok = preg_replace("~(</a>)~iU", '', $content);
echo $ok;
```

I need to control the $content...

I want to remove all  link in the $content....

even `<a href="xx"><img xxxx> </a>` all to remove A tag Just save `<img xxx>`...

How can I do?

I need edit the REGEX??

why I just can del the first one

Comment: what DOM?  is it a Class?

Comment: `$content = preg_replace('~<a.+?>(.*?)</a>~is', '$1', $content);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the anchors with their contents using [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument):

```
$html = <<<'EOS'
<a href="xx"><img src="http://example.com"> </a>
<a href="xx"><img src="http://example.com"> </a>
EOS;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query('//a') as $anchor) {
    $fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    // collecting the child nodes
    foreach ($anchor->childNodes as $node) {
        $fragment->appendChild($node);
    }
    // replace anchor with all child nodes
    $anchor->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $anchor);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Curious about the quotes in your heredoc `<<<'EOS'`

Comment: Habit, don't want any attempts made to evaluate variables; in fact, that part comes from my SO testing template :)

Comment: If 4 links. why I get it.<img src="http://example.com">
<a href="xx"><img src="http://example.com"></a>
<img src="http://example.com">
<a href="xx"><img src="http://example.com"></a>